# Propper usage of Microsoft Passport for SSO

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge

Recently, I got interested in Microsoft Edge and its SSO capabilities. However I could not find any documentation about that subject other than it's a part of Windows 10. Somewhere, I've read about FIDO and that Microsoft would make a reference implementation of the V2 standard but nothing beyond that. I'm not sure what's meant by Microsoft Passport other than it for sure isn't the msn login that was live in 2000 or so.

I've found the msCredentials object in Edge that I think might be a bridge to the Windows.Security.Credentials namespace.

The only function that it had was msCredentials.makeCredential but I don't know the parameters for it.

Could anyone help me with investigating that object/functions or anything you know about SSO in Edge?
Edge team, what's the status of this API and where is the documentation?

I'm currently running W10 build 10547 at my main desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Passport SDK was eventually replaced by the now defunct Windows Live SDK.

If you're looking to implement SSO with the Microsoft Accounts(live, hotmail,etc.) Identity Provider then I suggest you use the Authentication for the OneDrive API

https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/readme.htm

Unfortunately, Windows Authentication is not yet supported in Microsoft Edge so SSO with your AD account is not possible:

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9394494-support-windows-ntlm-kerberos-authentication

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/701fe232-574e-491b-80e5-2c88c83e4976/edge-browser-support-for-negotiatedntlmwindows-authentication?forum=win10itprogeneral